# PHP/MySQL/PDO Library - Distributing Information Out Of A Database? What's the most efficient way?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have keys for a project I made where I am trying to test a licensing system (Just for fun, and learning) a part that I thought I'd run into, is how to distribute the keys. I have about 100 keys in a database, and I'm trying to figure out the best way to distribute them. The database is layed out as follows,

```
ID (Auto Increment) | key
```

Using the PDO library, what is the most effective way to either to go in chronological order by ID? But even if I did chronological order, when I deleted the key that was given out, how would I go in chronological order? Or  maybe random ID number? I have no clue how to go about the most effective way to distribute these keys?

Comment: What do you mean by "distribute?"  Are you referring to publicly giving out the keys as the "licenses" to be looked up in your system?  In that case, I would use some form of cryptographic hash.

Comment: I would also not delete the keys from your database.  You're going to find out you want to know what keys you got rid of and where they went.  You might want to expand out this table to have additional meaningful columns

Comment: @DaOgre Then perhaps have another table called "In_Use" or something? You are right. Looking more into that part of just deleting doesn't seem too effective at actually managing the keys...Thank you =]

Comment: No need for an extra table.  If this is your "key" table, and the information is only relevant to your keys, there's no reason not to put it into this table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly...

You might try this query through PDO:

```
SELECT * FROM `table-name`
ORDER BY `ID` ASC
```

Then when you step through the rows in a while() loop from the execution's return, it will be in chronological order like you asked.

As far as losing ID's, like if you delete the key with ID # 10, your table will jump from 9 to 11 in the returned rows IDs.  When you add a new key, # 10 will not be used unless you specifically specify that ID when inserting.

EDIT:  From the phrasing of your question, it sounds like you may be concerned about how you set up the ID's for the keys.  Maybe you understand this already, but since you have Auto Increment, your IDs will be automatically generated when you insert new keys, so a new key would be assigned an ID of (ID of last inserted key) + 1.

Comment: Oh, awesome! Yes, this is pretty much what I needed...I really need to learn MySQL queries more...And just to ask some more :P, if I did a fetch(); in PDO, would that return the next in line? Thanks again =]

Comment: Yes, it would be like: while($row = $stmt->fetch()) -- right after you run $stmt->execute() --  and then you would get $row['ID'] and $row['key'] and manipulate them in the while loop.  At the end of the loop, the next row is fed.

Answer (score 1):

Chronology isn't exactly a feature of PDO, or for that matter whatever database driver you are using... it's more a matter of your schema.

Typically, a commonly employed field in any database structure is a "timestamp" or "created" field that holds the time the record was created in the database.  These fields can be MySQL datatype `TIMESTAMP` (in which case the driver will return seconds since the Unix Epoch), or `DATETIME` (in which case most drivers will attempt to return the language's native DateTime object if one exists.)  Even though monotonically-increasing primary keys imply a certain amount of chronological order when sorted, a timestamp field can record the exact time a record was created at the server, as well as update on change using `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.  So I would suggest adding this to your schema.

With such a field in your database, you can always sort your queries using:

`SORT BY timestamp_field_name ASC`

Also, if by "distribute" you mean some data will be publicly accessible by using this key as query param of some sort, I wouldn't use the monotonic primary key for the exact reason you described, especially if this is a "licensing" proof of concept, which if you mean a DRM-type thing should probably produce a complex string.  Hashed timestamps in a `UNIQUE` field, or the php `uniqid` function can produce values that can be stored in a `VARCHAR` database field with the `UNIQUE` key restraint.  This is if I have understood your described goal.